# How to invoke controller method from vf page on form submission?

Tags: class, visualforce

VF Page Code :

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" doctype="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" controller="Rforce_ESWebtoCase_CTR">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/css/validationEngine.jquery_Dacia.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
        <!---MaskPlugin---->
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MaskFuntion1}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MaskFuntion}"/>
        <!---ValidationPlugin---->
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery_min.js')}" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery.validationEngine-adriatic-hr.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery.validationEngine.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/Rforce_ESWebtoCase.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>
form{
   width:540px;
   background-color:#EDEDED;
   font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
   padding: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
}
div #button{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
input.text {
    border: 1px solid #DADCDE;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
p{
    font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
    color: #A2A5A4; 
    font-size: o.70em; 
}
h2{
    line-height: 1.5px;
    font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#CPF_Web__c,#email,#Phone,#Fname1,#Lname1,#description,#VIN_Web__c,#License_Number_Web__c,#Address,#CEP,#Complemento,#Cidade,#Estado,#ContactMobile{
    width: 410px;
}
#Numero{
    width: 150px;
}
#Endereço{
    width: 410px;
}
#left {
   float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
div #backbutton{
    float: right;
}
</style> 

        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonenviar').click(function() {
  alert('Button clicked');
  fileattachcheck();
});
});

       function fileattachcheck()  
            { 
            alert('inside filecheck'); 
                var ttl =document.getElementById("titleweb").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.titleweb}").value =ttl;

                var fn = document.getElementById("Fname").value;
                document.getElementById ("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.fname}").value =fn;

                var ln = document.getElementById("Lname").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.Lname}").value =ln;

                var ssn = document.getElementById("Surname").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.Surname}").value =ssn;

                var em = document.getElementById("email").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.email}").value =em;

                var ph = document.getElementById("phone").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.phone}").value =ph;

                var mob = document.getElementById("ContactMobile").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.ContactMobile}").value =mob;

                var no = document.getElementById("number").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.number}").value =no;

                var st = document.getElementById("Street").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.Street}").value =st;

                var flt = document.getElementById("flat").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.flat}").value =flt;

                var dr = document.getElementById("door").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.door}").value =dr;

                var ct = document.getElementById("city").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.city}").value =ct;

                var stt = document.getElementById("state").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.state}").value =stt;

                var vn = document.getElementById("vinno").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.vinno}").value =vn;

                var lc = document.getElementById("LicNo").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.LicNo}").value =lc;

                var kmtr = document.getElementById("km").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.km}").value =kmtr;

                var dsc = document.getElementById("description").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.description}").value =dsc;

                var ty = document.getElementById("Type").value;
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.Type}").value =ty;

            }        
            function showattachment(){
                var cn =document.getElementById("counter").value;
                cn++;
                alert(cn);
                document.getElementById("counter").value =cn;
                if(cn==0){
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att1}").style.display ="none";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att2}").style.display ="none";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att3}").style.display ="none";                
                }
                if(cn==1){

                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att1}").style.display ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att2}").style.display ="none";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att3}").style.display ="none";   
                }                        
                if(cn==2){
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att1}").style.display ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att2}").style.display ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att3}").style.display ="none";   
                } 
                if(cn==3){
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att1}").style.display  ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att2}").style.display ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att3}").style.display ="block";   
                }                       
            }
            function shownoattachment(){
                var cn=document.getElementById("counter").value;
                cn--;

                document.getElementById("counter").value=cn;
                if(cn==0){
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att1}").style.display  ="none";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att2}").style.display  ="none";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att3}").style.display  ="none";                
                }
                if(cn==1){
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att1}").style.display ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att2}").style.display ="none";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att3}").style.display ="none";   
                }                        
                if(cn==2){
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att1}").style.display ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att2}").style.display ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att3}").style.display ="none";    
                } 
                if(cn==3){
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att1}").style.display ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att2}").style.display ="block";
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.ESForm.BlockID.att3}").style.display ="block";   
                }                  
            }  
        </script>

    <c:Form_css />    
    </head>   
    <form id="formID">
          <div id="fields">
            <label for="title">Tratamiento*</label><br/>
            <select id="titleweb" name="titleweb" >
            <option value="Mr.">Sr.</option> 
            <option value="Mrs.">Sra.</option>
            <option value="Miss">Sta.</option>
            </select><br/><hr color="white"></hr>
     <Label for="Lname" >APELLIDO 1*</Label>      
 <br></br> 
<input id="Lname" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input " maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:500px" />
<br></br>

<span>       
<Label for="Fname" >NOMBRE*</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<Label for="Surname" >APELLIDO 2*</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="Fname" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input" maxlength="30" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px"/> 
&nbsp;
<input id="Surname" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:235px" />
</span>

  <hr color="white"></hr>

  <Label for="email" >E-mail*</Label><br></br>
   <input id="email" maxlength="80" size="48" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" style="width:500px" />

    <hr color = "white"></hr>

                    <Label for="phone" >Teléfono fijo</Label><br></br>
                    <input id="phone" maxlength="10" name="phone" size="48" style="width:500px" />
                    <hr color = "white"></hr>

                    <Label for="Mobile">Teléfono móvil*</Label><br></br>
                    <input id="ContactMobile" class="validate[required,custom[telephone]]" maxlength="10" size="48"   style="width:500px" />
                    <hr color = "white"></hr>
<span>       
<Label for="Dnumber" >Nº</Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     
<Label for="Street" >Calle</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="number" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" />
&nbsp;
<input id="Street" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:238px" />
</span>  

<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<span>        
<Label for="flat" >Piso</Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<Label for="door" >Puerta</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="flat" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" />
&nbsp;
<input id="door" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:238px" />
</span>
<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<span>        
<Label for="city" >Ciudad</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<Label for="state" >Provincia</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="city" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" />
&nbsp;
<input id="state" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" />
</span>
<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>
<span>       
<Label for="vin" >Chasis</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<Label for="regno" >Matricula</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="vinno" maxlength="17" size="20" type="text" />
&nbsp;
<input id="LicNo" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" />
</span>  

<br></br> 
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<Label for="km">Kilómetros</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="km" type="text" maxlength="20" size="20" /> 
 <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>
               <Label for="casetype">Tipo*</Label><br></br> 
               <select  id="Type" name="casetype" >
               <option value="Information Request">Solicitud de información</option>
               <option value="Complaint">Reclamación</option>
               <option value="Service Request">Sugerencia</option>
               <option value="Other">Other</option>
               </select><br/>
               <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>
   <Label for="description">Descripción*</Label><br></br>
<Textarea  id="description" class="validate[required]"  maxlength = "800" rows="8" cols="57" />    
 <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>
        Adjuntar documento 
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="showattachment();"/>
        <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="shownoattachment()"/>
              <input type = "submit" name ="submit" value ="Enviar" id = "buttonenviar"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="counter" value=""/>


    </div>

    </form> 
    <apex:form id="ESForm">
        <apex:pageBlock id="BlockID">
            <apex:inputhidden id="titleweb" value="{!strTitle}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="fname" value="{!strFirstName}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="lname" value="{!strLastName}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="Surname" value="{!strSecondSurName}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="email" value="{!strEmail}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="phone" value="{!strPhone}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="ContactMobile" value="{!strMobilePhone}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="number" value="{!strNo}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="Street" value="{!strStreet}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="flat" value="{!strFlat}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="door" value="{!strDoor}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="city" value="{!strCity}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="state" value="{!strState}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="vinno" value="{!strVinno}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="LicNo" value="{!strLicenceNo}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="km" value="{!strKilometer}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="Type" value="{!strCaseType}"/>
            <apex:inputhidden id="description" value="{!strDescription}"/>
            <apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>
            <apex:inputFile value="{!attach.body}" filename="{!attach.name}" id="att1" style="display:none;"/><br/>
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attach1.body}" filename="{!attach1.name}" id="att2" style="display:none;"/><br/>
            <apex:inputFile value="{!attach2.body}" filename="{!attach2.name}" id="att3" style="display:none;"/><br/>
        </apex:pageBlock>


    </apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

Controller Code :

```
public class Rforce_ESWebtoCase_CTR {
    public String strFirstName{get;set;}
    public String strLastName{get;set;}
    public String strSecondSurName{get;set;}
    public String strEmail{get;set;}
    public String strPhone{get;set;}
    public String strMobilePhone{get;set;}
    public String strNo{get;set;}
    public String strStreet{get;set;}
    public String strFlat{get;set;}
    public String strDoor{get;set;}
    public String strCity{get;set;}
    public String strState{get;set;}
    public String strVinno{get;set;}
    public String strLicenceNo{get;set;}
    public Integer strKilometer{get;set;}
    public String strCaseType{get;set;}
    public String strDescription{get;set;}
    public String strTitle{get;set;}
    public Case cas{get;set;}
    public Blob attchmentBody{get;set;}
    public Attachment attach {get;set;}
    public Attachment attach1 {get;set;}
    public Attachment attach2 {get;set;}
    public Attachment attach3 {get;set;}
    public Attachment attach4 {get;set;}
    public Boolean att1 {get;set;}
    public Boolean att2 {get;set;}
    public Boolean att3 {get;set;}
    public Boolean att4 {get;set;}
    public Boolean att5 {get;set;}
    List<Attachment> lattlist=new List<Attachment>();
    public Rforce_ESWebtoCase_CTR() {
          attach = new Attachment();
          attach1 =new Attachment();
          attach2 =new Attachment();
          attach3 =new Attachment();
          attach4 =new Attachment();
    }
    public pagereference insertcase(){
    system.debug('Inside insert case method');
        Case cas = new Case(FirstName_Web__c= strFirstName , LastName_Web__c= strLastName , Second_name_Web__c = strSecondSurName ,SuppliedEmail= strEmail , SuppliedPhone= strPhone , Cell_Phone_Web__c= strMobilePhone , Address_Web__c = strNo+strStreet+strFlat+strDoor , City_Web__c= strCity , State_Web__c= strState , VIN_Web__c= strVinno , License_Number_Web__c= strLicenceNo , Kilometer__c= strKilometer , Type= strCaseType , Description= strDescription , Title_Web__c = strTitle ,Subject = strCaseType ,Priority = System.Label.Rforce_CASPriority_Normal ,Status = System.Label.Rforce_CASStatus_New , Origin = System.Label.Rforce_CASOrigin_DaciaSite ,CaseBrand__c = System.Label.Rforce_CASBrand_Dacia ,Language_Web__c = System.Label.Rforce_CASLanguage_Spanish ,CaseSubSource__c = System.Label.Rforce_CASSubsource_Webform , From__c = System.Label.Rforce_CASFrom_Customer , CountryCase__c = System.Label.Rforce_CASCountryCase_Spain);  
        insert cas;
        attach.ParentId=cas.Id;
        attach1.ParentId=cas.Id;
        attach2.ParentId=cas.Id;      
        if(attach.body!=null)   
         lattlist.add(attach);
         if(attach1.body!=null)   
         lattlist.add(attach1);
         if(attach2.body!=null)   
         lattlist.add(attach2); 
          insert lattlist;
          return null;
     }     

}
```

I need to call the insertcase method in which the case creation is done. What I want to do is , if I click on the enviar button all the values for case have to be passed to the controller and the case has to be created along with the attachment.. Please provide me a solution.. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using html button instead of pageblockbuttons then you have only option to use apex:actionfunction component.

Actionfunction component provides support for invoking controller action methods directly from JavaScript code using an AJAX request.

Here how it will work.

1. Add following code inside your end form tag

[image]

2. call this **sayHello** method from your javascript method.

   $('#buttonenviar').click(function() {
   alert('Button clicked');
   fileattachcheck();
   sayHello();
   });

You can read more about actionfunction here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm